HTML <audio> context menu position
Don't know if it's a bug related to Chrome and Edge or something wrong with the HTML, but the context menu for audio controls, when html contains multiple controls, always open attached to the latest control.
The red circle in the image shows where the user clicks.

<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
    <audio controls>
      <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    </audio>
  </body>
</html>

At the moment I'm running the latest Chrome version.

UPDATED PICTURE



So, what do you exactly want to do here?

I want to be sure the HTML is valid and that's probably something related to Chrome. Maybe other users are facing the same issue and fixed it somehow.

but the context menu for audio controls always open attached to the latest control. does that mean you want the audio controls to be in a separate new line?

@M.Riyan Ok, I've realized the example wasn't pretty clear. I have updated the picture, showing stacked controls. No matter which "3 dots" I click, the context menu always appears at the very bottom.

This bug occurs in Chromium, which is the basis for Chrome. Therefore, the same issue is occurring in browsers like Edge as well. It has already been reported on the Chromium forum.
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/342961838
